# Get class of generic

Tags: java, class, generics, types, parameterized

My class starts with

```
public abstract class LastActionHero<H extends Hero>(){
```

Now somewhere in the code I want to write `H.class` but that isn't possible (like `String.class` or `Integer.class` is).

Can you tell me how I can get the `Class` of the generic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide the type dynamically, however the compiler doesn't do this for you automagically.

```
public abstract class LastActionHero<H extends Hero>(){
    protected final Class<H> hClass;
    protected LastActionHero(Class<H> hClass) {
        this.hClass = hClass;
    }
    // use hClass how you like.
}
```

BTW: It not impossible to get this dynamically, but it depends on how it is used. e.g

```
public class Arnie extends LastActionHero<MuscleHero> { }
```

It is possible to determine that Arnie.class has a super class with a Generic parameter of MuscleHero.

```
public class Arnie<H extend Hero> extends LastActionHero<H> { }
```

The generic parameter of the super class will be just `H` in this case.

Answer (score 15):

We do it in the following way:

```
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        if (persistentClass == null) {
            this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        return persistentClass;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to keep reference to your parameterized type like having an attribute of

```
private Class<H> clazz;
```

And create a setter or a constructor that takes in a `Class<H>`.

Parameterized Types are erased at runtime, hence why you can't do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without passing in the class:

```
public abstract class LastActionHero<H extends Hero>() {
  Class<H> clazz = (Class<H>) DAOUtil.getTypeArguments(LastActionHero.class, this.getClass()).get(0);
}
```

You need two functions from this file: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/dao/src/main/java/com/googlecode/genericdao/dao/DAOUtil.java

For more explanation: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Answer (score 0):

You can't- the type is erased at run-time and exists only at compile-time.